# Redirect non-logged in users from user-account to a custom login page without effecting lost password page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So I have this snippet that redirects the user-account page when the user is logged out to my custom login page but the problem is that the lost password is in the user-account page (user-account/lost-password) and I want it to go to it. Can you help?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'web_redirect_to_specific_page' );

function web_redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( is_page('user-account') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'https://www.website.com/login/', 301 ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome Mohnas, take out `is_page('user-account') &&` in your code. it is also telling the page to redirect if you are on page = user-account

Comment: Have you tried this hook - add_action('wp_logout','redirect_after_logout');

Comment: HI Omukiguy, I want to redirect user-account when user is logged out to login so why remove it? The problem is just that it also redirects user-account/lost-password when I am logged out while I need it

Comment: Hi Mujuonly, I have this hook to redirect customers after logout to the homepage but the problem is when he is automatically logged out, it will redirect to user-account if I didn't use redirect